# Why is this Bash command using regex not replacing my brackets?

Tags: bash, shell, find, regular-expression, rename

I have this command to go through all my files in my `Music` directory, and all subdirectories, and replace any square brackets in the file name with rounded brackets:

```
find /home/Music/ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/\[/\(/g' "{}" \;
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't return any errors, it just doesn't make the replacements.

I thought I properly escaped the characters. Where am I going wrong?

Also, eventually I"ll want to replace curly brackets, `{}`, with rounded brackets , `()`, as well. Just thought I'd mention that now in case curly brackets came with yet more complications.

Comment: This should work as long as you have files with spaces in their names. What *nix are you on?

Comment: Would you mind showing some sample directory data in this question?

Comment: Try adding `-v` (and optionally `-n`) to the rename part to see what is it doing. Also, you might need to modify the `s///` option to be `s///g` to replace all matched characters, not only the first one it encounters.

Comment: `rename` is not a standard tool, so the various implementations have different syntax. Have you checked that you use the right syntax?

Comment: @terdon: That was my mistake. I totally forgot `"* *"` would look for files with spaces in the name, whereas what I need to do is `"*[*"`. If you convert your comment to an answer I'll mark you correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can see why it wouldn't work is if there are no files with spaces in their names. The pattern `"* *"` will only match if the filename has a space.

If you want to find files whose name contains square brackets, do

```
find /home/Music/ -depth -name "*[*" -execdir rename 's/\[/\(/g' "{}" \;
```

Comment: `-name '*\[*'` or `-name '*[[]*'` would be more portable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main `rename` implementations on Linux:

- The one that comes with `perl` (which is probably the one you were expecting)
- The one that comes with util-linux (probably the one you have).

The syntax for the one that comes with `util-linux` would be:

```
find ... -execdir rename '[' '(' {} +
```

However, that would only replace one occurrence of `[`.

`perl`'s `rename` might be called `prename` on your system.

An alternative to `rename` is zsh's `zmv`. It would take care of descending directories depth first and avoid problems with collisions.

In zsh:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(**/)(* *)' '$1${2//\[/(}'
```

And for converting both `{}` and `[]` to `()`:

```
zmv -n '(**/)(* *)' '$1${${2//[]\}]/)}//[[{]/(}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
for i in `find o -type f`; do new="${i/\[/(}" ; if [ "${i}" != "${new}" ]; then mv ${i} ${new} ; echo "Moving ${i} to ${new}"; fi ; done
```

If the file names contain spaces, try the following:

```
OLDIFS=${IFS} ; IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") ; for i in `find o -type f`; do new="${i/\[/(}" ; if [ "${i}" != "${new}" ]; then mv ${i} ${new} ; echo "Moving ${i} to ${new}"; fi ; done; IFS=${OLDIFS}
```

Comment: You're using command substitution without setting IFS (though the OP was explicitly wanting to rename files with spaces in their name) `${i/../}` is to replace one occurrence while the OP used the `g` flag, you forgot to quote some variables. That won't work properly if directory names contain `[`

Comment: Modified answer to handle spaces.